# I changed the form icon and the program won't compile

Tags: vb.net, forms, basic

I tried to change the default icon of my applicatoin and now the form gives an error when I compile it, and I don't know to undo the action and go back to the original icon.

I don't know if this helps, but I changed the icon in the properties box: 
[properties box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGcyo.png)

Comment: If only there was a way for us to know what the error message was.

Comment: That's not the Icon of the Application, it's the icon of a Form (The app's Icon is in the Project's properties, in the `Application` panel). You can remove it, it will use the default icon. BTW, you didn't say how you tried to change it and, as already mentioned, what is the build error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.  Right mouse button click on the text label part of the Property item (property name) which bring up a context menu with **Reset** as one of the options - click it and see what happens.

Comment: The way to say "thank you " on Stack Overflow is to accept the answer by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer.